# React Native Can't find variable : meterData

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this List variable called meterData and I want to insert the list items' value to a React native Elements components `ListItem.Accordion` this is my code so far
the error i'm getting is `Can't find variable : meterData`

```
function getReadingOrder(Emp_Number,{navigation}){
  
  fetch('http://somewebsite/gecol/partner/api.php?emp_number='+`${Emp_Number}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }
})
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((data) => { var xml2js = require('xml2js');
            var meterData = "";
            var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
            parser.parseString(data, function(err,result){
            //Extract the value from the data element
            const meterData = [{
              servicePoint:result['counter']['serviceNumber'],
              counternumber:result['counter']['counternumber'],
              consumer:result['counter']['consumername'],
              consumpationtype:result['counter']['consumpationtype'],
              currentread:result['counter']['currentread'],
              currentdate:result['counter']['currentdate'],
              lastread:result['counter']['lastread'],
              lastdate:result['counter']['lastdate'],
              consumpation:result['counter']['consumpation'],
              phonenumber:result['counter']['phonenumber']
            }]
            // getRounds(meterData);
      });
    });
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true);
    return (  
      <SafeAreaProvider >
        <View style={ReaderHome.Accordion}>
          {meterData.map((meter, i) => (
          <ListItem.Accordion 
            content={
              <>
              <Avatar size={64} icon={{ name: 'home', type: 'AntDesign' }} containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#1f95c0' }}/>
              <ListItem.Content>
                <ListItem.Title style={{left:10}}><Text style={ReaderHome.ConsumerName}>meter.consumer</Text></ListItem.Title>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{left:10}}><Text style={ReaderHome.ServiceNumber}>meter.servicePoint</Text></ListItem.Subtitle>
                </ListItem.Content>
              </>
            }
            isExpanded={expanded}
            onPress={() => {
              setExpanded(!expanded);
            }}
              >
              <ListItem key={i} onPress={console.log('s')} bottomDivider>
                <Avatar title={''} source={''} />
                  <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title>{meter.currentread}</ListItem.Title>
                    <ListItem.Subtitle>{meter.lastread}</ListItem.Subtitle>
                  </ListItem.Content>
                  <ListItem.Chevron />
              </ListItem>
          </ListItem.Accordion>))}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaProvider>);
      
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meterData` is declared inside the then scope of the fetch, so you cannot access it from outside afterwards. Also it won't be available when rendering as fetch is asynchronous.

Since it's asynchronous this needs some refactoring, check out this [post](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/) on how to fetch with hooks inside a component.